# Difference between Tick data and NASDAQ ITCH VIEW

Tags: data, nasdaq, tick

Could any one explain the difference

Answer (score 2):

What Tick data you have in mind? NASDAQ ITCH is tick data but you have to construct the limit order book yourself to keep track of the best bid and ask price for each stocks. Not a trivial task. If you get TAQ data, you will get the best bid and ask (NBBO) but TAQ data has some issues like no odd-lot trades and trades are not mark buyer or seller initiated.